# Merging datas using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

i am trying to find a way to merge datas in a sqlite database using the cli.

example :

TABLE1 with col1(keys) & col2 (values1)

```
╔══════╦═════════╗
║ col1 ║ values1 ║
╠══════╬═════════╣
║ 1234 ║     456 ║
║ 1235 ║     789 ║
╚══════╩═════════╝
```

TABLE2 with col1(keys) & col2 (values2)

```
╔══════╦═════════╗
║ col1 ║ values2 ║
╠══════╬═════════╣
║ 1233 ║     235 ║
║ 1234 ║     457 ║
║ 1235 ║     790 ║
╚══════╩═════════╝
```

Target :
TABLE3 with col1(keys) & col2 (values1) & col3 (values2)

```
╔══════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ col1 ║ values1 ║ values2 ║
╠══════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 1233 ║ NULL    ║     235 ║
║ 1234 ║ 456     ║     457 ║
║ 1235 ║ 789     ║     790 ║
╚══════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

How can I do that in SQL ?

Comment: Try first creating table3 and doing this:

sqlite> .mode insert new_table
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
INSERT INTO "new_table" VALUES('hello',10);
INSERT INTO "new_table" VALUES('goodbye',20);
sqlite>

from here:

https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CREATE TABLE AS`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/61a9c/1/0)**

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(col1 INT, values1 INT);

INSERT INTO TABLE1
VALUES (1234,456), (1235,789);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2(col1 INT, values2 INT);

INSERT INTO TABLE2
VALUES (1233,235), (1234,457), (1235,790);
```

Main query:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3
AS
SELECT col1, MAX(values1) AS values1, MAX(values2) AS values2
FROM(
   SELECT t1.col1 AS col1, t1.values1 AS values1, t2.values2 AS values2
   FROM TABLE1 t1
   LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
     ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t2.col1 AS col1, t1.values1 AS values1, t2.values2 AS values2
   FROM TABLE2 t2
   LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t1
     ON t1.col1 = t2.col1) as tab
GROUP BY col1;
```

It may be much easier when SQLite supports `FULL OUTER JOIN` then there is no need for subquery and `UNION ALL` using `ORACLE`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9e02/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3
AS
SELECT 
   COALESCE(t1.col1, t2.col1) AS col1,
   t1.values1 AS values1,
   t2.values2 AS values2
FROM TABLE1 t1
FULL JOIN TABLE2 t2
  ON t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```

or `SQL SERVER`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/747fc/1/1)**

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(t1.col1, t2.col1) AS col1,
    t1.values1 AS values1,
    t2.values2 AS values2
INTO TABLE3
FROM TABLE1 t1
FULL JOIN TABLE2 t2
  ON t1.col1 = t2.col1;
```

*Warning:*
After initial table is created you have to `INSERT` using:

**[SqlFiddleDemo4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9f258/1/0)**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3(col1,values1, values2)
SELECT ...
```